# iOS 7 doesn't show more than one line when option is longer than screen size

Tags: html, ios7, html-select

iOS 7 does not show more than one line in html `option`s:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo test test test test test test </option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It just truncates it with ellipsis. Has anyone else noticed this with just a standard HTML `option`?

Perhaps it is an iOS 7 bug because it was not happening on iOS6? I pulled this directly from [the w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp).

To reproduce, take your iPhone running iOS 7 and go [to this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKvJF/).

Obviously you can see the question once selected. But with a mobile optimized phone you will not see the entire question.

Unless I am missing something here.

Comment: What do you mean by “one line”? A `select` element is supposed to show just one option in the initial display. If you mean that this option is truncated (how?), even when no style sheets are used, please say so in the question (and its title).

Comment: Ok i edited the heading. Take what you see there above, or go to w3 schools and see there basic example. Keep your iOS 7 device (phone/ipod) in portrait mode and press the select button. It only shows what is allowed in the screen space and the rest is truncated. This also happens on most Android Native browsers but... yeah its the android native browser. Basically, it should wrap and show the whole sentence like it does in iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it now requires the `<optgroup>` standard to wrap the options.

Problem solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "requires the standard"?

Comment: It requires an <optgroup> tag for the options to show the full option when it would extend beyond the width of the iPhone. This does not fix the android issue though. But putting an empty <optgroup> and then closing it "</optgroup>" after your options will fix it. So if you have an option that is <option>This is a really long option that would not show on one line in an iphone</option>, you need to wrap the options with the optgroup even if it is just one group.

Answer (score 9):

Add an empty `optgroup` at the end of the select list:

```
 <select>
  <option selected="" disabled="">Select a value</option>
  <option>Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack</option>
  <option>Quirky spud boys can jam after zapping five worthy Polysixes</option>
  <option>The wizard quickly jinxed the gnomes before they vaporized</option>
  <option>All questions asked by five watched experts amaze the judge</option>
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
 </select>
```

Comment: For future visitors: this worked for me, but it did lead to [a new issue with multiple items seemingly being selected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31913173/419956).